# How to override an ng-click directive to not automatically run $apply

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

Found some close questions , but not exactly the one I need to ask.

I have multiple elements with ng-click events.
For a majority of them (of a specific class), I don't need to actually run an angular digest cycle after click. The result of the click on these elements does not affect any scope variable (let's say for example they just print out a console.log).

What I want to do is to react conditionally to an ngClick, where say elements of a specific css class will not have the automatic $apply at the end.

Edit:

What I ended up doing was replace the ng-click, ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave with the corresponding javascript replacements.

I did this for two reasons:
1. I don't actually affect the scope variables on those clicks, so I don't need to run a digest after each (I have mouseenters, so you can imaging that generated a lot of digest cycles for no reason).
2. This is content that I load late in the page loading sequence from another source (ng-bind), so it has to be sanitized by angular and then compiled. This took a log of time (almost a second) because I have many such links, and that was holding back the display of the content.

Comment: Do you have the option to not use `ng-click` on those particular elements and instead bind using `.on('click', function () { })` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I highly recommend against this, as the $apply in your application shouldn't really be affecting anything (even performance). You'll have to create your own directive for this.

**HTML**

```
<div data-no-apply-click="myFunction()">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
.directive('noApplyClick', function ($parse) {
    return {
        compile : function ($element, attr) {
            var fn = $parse(attr['noApplyClick']);
            return function (scope, element, attr) {
                element.on('click', function (event) {
                    fn(scope, {
                        $event : event,
                        $element : element
                    });
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/gj54bjsh/

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, It seems like a good one. I didn't however understand why this doesn't affect performance, I noticed that on every click, angular runs a digest cycle. wouldn't that affect performance?

Comment: I didn't however understand why this doesn't affect performance, I noticed that on every click, angular runs a digest cycle. wouldn't that affect performance?

Comment: That's the point of angular, it runs these digest/apply cycles. Unless your code is not structured correctly having them run aren't really a problem. I've written very large scale apps and it's been no issue.

Comment: I wanted to add that we've got a app that had THOUSANDS of binds that we are working to clean up. Using this was an easy way to drop some CSS without the whole system $digesting everything.

Comment: Thanks, it give me an idea to create directive for click with condition check.

Comment: It certainly can impact performance. $apply will run a digest at the rootScope level and traverse all the way through each child scope, re-evaluating each $$watcher, twice.